# Remove Objects with same key values from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and want to remove all the objects that have a specific key value.

the Array looks something like this:

```
var myArray = [{name: "a", value: "b"}, {name: "a", value: "d"}, {name: "f", value: "r"}, {name: "g", value: "q"}];
```

In this case, I would like to have all objects with the name `a` removed form the array.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` is what you are looking for, check this out for more information.

```js
const arr = [{name: "a", value: "b"}, {name: "a", value: "d"}, {name: "f", value: "r"}, {name: "g", value: "q"}];

console.log(arr.filter((item) => {
  return item.name !== "a";
}));
```

Check this out for more information on `Array.prototype.filter`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter